# Get a list of the five last logins for x user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, relational-database

So I've got this task where I'm supposed to output a list of the last five logins by the currently logged in user.

So like this:

Person A logs in at 12.00 12/12/12.

Person A logs in again at 12.00 12/01/13.

And so on.

This needs to work up to a list of five, once that limit is reached the first login (12.00 12/12/12 in this case) is to be taken out of view.

What I've got so far is a Login system with remember tokens and some simple authorization for the login itself (doing it from scratch and going back to some details fom Michael Hartl's tutorial). Right now, I can list the current time that the user logged in, but not the previous 'versions'.

**So, this is my view:**

```
<% if signed_in? %>
<h1>Welcome, <%= current_user.name %>!</h1>
<p>You were last logged in on:</p>
<ul>
    <li><%= current_user.lastlogin %></li>
</ul>
<%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% else %>
... (state for non logged in users)
<% end %>
```

**This is my user class:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :lastlogin
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  ...(validation following this)
```

**And this is my sessions_controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to root_path
else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**And here we have the sign_in function**

```
module SessionsHelper
 def sign_in(user)
 # user.update_attribute(:lastlogin, Time.now)
   user.touch(:lastlogin)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
 end
end
```

I'm looking for ideas on how to tackle this problem.

Another thing that I've forgotten to mention is that the view layer needs to be modified to some extent so as to loop through the five login times and output them in order, as opposed to hard coding in five list items.

One thing that I'm thinking of is setting up a relationship between a table with five fields corresponding to one user. And then upon sign in (or sign out) take the :lastlogin value and push it into a field in the table.

Then when all fields have been filled, look at the first date and replace it with the new.

So what I'm thinking is something like

```
def sign_in
  user.touch(:lastlogin)
  # push :lastlogin value into field in LoginsTable
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  self.current_user = user
end
```

I am quite new to Ruby on Rails and might be way off here. I've tried searching for functionality like the one I'm explaining here, and all I've gotten is various plugins/full-out gems that handle this and everything else when it comes to Authentication and so forth, which isn't really 'needed' in this case as it's just a small time project for myself.

Cheers!

Edit:

The futile attempt at pushing into the user_logins table.

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    user.update_attribute(:lastlogin, Time.now)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
    login_time = UserLogins.create(:login_time Time.now, :user_id current_user)
  end
end
```

Now this is obviously not working. I'm not too sure on exactly how to loop through the login_times either in the view layer. But I reckon I'll get it working eventually, now that you put me on the right track :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get yourself into a messy pickle if you hardcode 5 fields to hold the last 5 login dates, instead consider having a table to store login history for all users. A simple table "user_logins" with `id`, `user_id` and `login_time` would suffice. 
Write to this table every time the user logs in, then in your view just select the top 5 results ordered by `login_time`, descending.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. What I'm thinking right now is making a logins table, with a :datetime col and a :user_id col. 

And then setting has_many logins on the user and writing to the :datetime column in the Logins table on sign in. 

If that makes sense. 

The one thing I'm worried about is the actual pushing of :lastlogin into the table. Can't recall having done that with Rails before. Then again, maybe I have..

Comment: you might also add a before filter or Observer or rake task or something that will cleanup the unneeded logins table entries as something based on logins will grow very quickly with usage! :)

Comment: Oh this won't be used very much at all. 

What I'm having trouble with right now is the actual push of Time.now or :lastlogin into the user_logins (that has the columns of id, login_time and user_id). 

I'll edit the main post to showcase my futile attempt at a push, which just had wrong written all over it.

Answer (score 0):

on this line

```
login_time = UserLogins.create(:login_time Time.now, :user_id current_user)
```

You're creating the hash object wrong. Ruby 1.9 hash syntax is

```
some_var: "some value"
```

not

```
:some_var "some value"
```

Good luck!

Also decompose that UserLogins object a little. Since you're using Time.now have the UserLogins object set the time which reduces your method to a monodic one.

Side notes:

You shouldn't name a Model object plural as that'll get confusing in Rails.

Comment: Hey! Working on this stuff right now, realised the Pluralized name of my model and corrected that. Think I solved the relational stuff aswell so now I've entered a bunch of login_time 's into a User ID. 

Time to try and push it into view and sort it, then sort out the creation. 

And thanks for pointing out the syntax fault. I've been sitting neck deep in this language for the past week but it's still quite alien to me.

Comment: don't give up! I think you'll find Ruby to be quite a nice language. Rails can be a bear at times though, so don't confuse the two! lol If I may suggest it, working through these may help you a bit with the ruby part. http://rubykoans.com/

Comment: also part of what you're doing can probably be simplified with a little renaming. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html As basically you'd be using the *created_at* column

Comment: Hey Dave! Thanks for the good tips. I'll definately check out Koans. 

At the moment I'm trying to pull out the created_at col but to no avail. 

Basically what I've got is @user.user_logins.created_at. I've tried a couple of different things but they all throw up: 

undefined method `created_at' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation

Hopefully I'll figure out how to solve this in a timely fashion :)

Comment: did you run rake db:migrate? :)

Comment: That I did. db:migrate and db:test:prepare

Pushing everything up to github now. Link is coming.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22855/discussion-between-kasper-lewau-and-engineerdave)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use devise gem as it maintains authuntication and also history of user logins So you can easily get Last five login user applying query on user model and order desc by last login

Comment: I heard about Devise, but to start off I wanted to make something myself (although I did recieve a ton of help from Dave..). Definately gonna have a look at Devise and OmniAuth for my next project, which is on a bigger scale than this little thingy here. But it's a good thing to know that this kind of functionality is built in already, thanks :)

Comment: :) yeah @KasperLewau; We are here to share knowledge with each other, thanks for aperication.